# Not smooth validation accuracy vs test accuracy. When to stop

Tags: conv-neural-network, accuracy, keras

I have a convolutional model with this training history.

[image]

Validation accuracy is growing slowly but it is almost flat.

The net is a two conv+maxpool layers and 3 dense layers. The training dataset images are synthetically modified in each epoch (rotated and moved) and the original number of images are around 34K

Looking the accuracy and loss evolution do you think that it growth it still training?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Accuracy can change dramatically with small shifts in parameters. I'm not aware of a more sophisticated procedure than squinting at the graphs and calling it a day. Or something like this. http://blog.dlib.net/2018/02/automatic-learning-rate-scheduling-that.html Perhaps you could run the training several times and take an average, but that's a lot of work for something that's not really well-specified to start.

Comment: Have you seen Jeff Benshetler's suggestion to [cross-validate](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-know-a-neural-network-is-stuck-in-a-local-optima) **and** [How to avoid local minimum in recurrent neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292741/how-to-avoid-local-minimum-in-recurrent-neural-network)? - Edit question to describe your algorithm for more help. Accuracy *does* continue to improve, jumping up and down; smoother and eventually flattening says it's working more efficiently and near finish. Try test data that you know will work better, compare.